# Higher order funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sanitization, serverside-javascript, high-order-component

I am having issues creating a High Order Function to trim white spaces

```js
const { trim } = require('validator')

const whiteSpace2 = () => (req:any) => {
  Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof req.body[key] === 'string') req.body[key] = trim(req.body[key])
  })
}

fastify.post('/login', (req:any, res:any) => {
  whiteSpace2()
  console.log(req.body)
  return res.code(403).send('error')
})
```

The function never gets executed

Comment: `const trimmer = whiteSpace2(); trimmer(req); console.log(req.body);`

Comment: you should pass `req` as parameter to `whiteSpace2` function.

Comment: @hackape I know i can do that, but I would like to send no arguments, using `express` I can set a middleware like this:

sanitize () {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    
  }
}

Comment: Then why don't you set it as middleware.

Comment: You've defined `whiteSpace2` to be a function that when called returns another function that needs to be passed `req` when it is called.  So, when you execute `whiteSpace2()`, ALL that does is return another function - no actual processing takes place until you call that other function and pass `req` to it.  So, your call to `whiteSpace2()` right now is doing nothing.  Further, there doesn't appear to be any reason to write it this way.